# c# asp.net - Search items in DataList and display them

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, datalist

I have a DataList connected to a database

Database:
`ID, ProductName, ProductPrice, ProductDescription, ProductImage`

So on my website, the datalist will display all the items inside my database.

I want to add a search box on the website that searches for specific `ProductName` and display it.

So Example,

Before Search:

`Toliet Paper A, Toliet Paper B`

After Search for "B":

`Toliet Paper B`

Comment: have you tried to code if yes then share your code and explain where you stucked

Comment: No i have not tried to code this. I'm not sure how or where to start

Comment: You have displayed all value in datalist in website right.

Comment: The DataList itself has nothing to do with searching. Since you show all data in your webpage you already have a data source. In your code-behind or controller (depending on the type of your project), use Linq to filter that data source before assigning it to the DataList.DataSource property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this example. I'm sure it should be very easy to refract:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/search-record-in-datagridview-C-Sharp/